# Type definition file

Tags: javascript, typescript, .d.ts

Is it possible to write a type definition for the next function?

```
define('ComponentName', ['_', 'jQuery'], function(_, $) {
   ...
});
```

The problem is that the parameters "_" (lodash) and "jQuery" are not recognized as such inside the function.

In addition, a function can be called with a variable number of arguments, for example only with jQuery:

```
define('ComponentName', ['jQuery'], function($) {
   ...
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
interface ComponentTypes {
    // Replace with actual types. 
    MyComponent: unknown;
    _: unknown;
    jQuery: unknown;
}

function define<D extends keyof ComponentTypes,
    A1 extends keyof ComponentTypes>
    (d: D, deps: [A1], f: (a1: ComponentTypes[A1]) => void);
function define<D extends keyof ComponentTypes,
    A1 extends keyof ComponentTypes, A2 extends keyof ComponentTypes>
    // TODO: Where does ComponentTypes[D] enter into this?
    (d: D, deps: [A1, A2], f: (a1: ComponentTypes[A1], a2: ComponentTypes[A2]) => void);
function define(d: string, deps: string[], f: Function) {
    // ...
}

define("MyComponent", ["_", "jQuery"], function (_, $) {
    // ...
});
define("MyComponent", ["jQuery"], function ($) {
    // ...
});
```